# Many-to-many relation and form with extra field

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, many-to-many

I am struggling with Many-to-Many model and form. What is the best way to show extra `level` field when creating a new `Person` with skill. I am going also to edit it later.

I am trying to achieve an effect in forms like that:

```
[input text] name
[select] skill name (there are choices in the model)
[input text] level of the skill
```

I tried things which people were suggesting but I couldn't make it to work. For example inlineformset + through.

Later on, I would like also to give the user a chance to add multiple sets of skill+level, maybe it is worth to think about it in advance?

My models and form:

```
class PersonSkill(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey('Skill', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[(1, 'working'),
                                                     (2, 'advanced'),
                                                     (3, 'champion')], null=True, blank=True)

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField('Skill', through='PersonSkill', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name',)
```

Comment: Your models are perfectly fine. What exactly is your problem? You can simply input your required fields by making a separate form of skills (prolly inline) to show skills and in your POST request your will create the person object with all the selected list of skills like this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I am not sure how to show Person form together with Skill.name and PersonSkill.level fields to let users use those fields. If I would create form like above + add skill field, it only returns Skill.name without PersonSkill.level.